# How to choose correct table using QueryTable, WebTables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pull multiple tables from multiple webpages. They're all identical, the only thing that differs between pages is the data in the tables and the url. I've been trying to use Web tables with the `.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables` however the website is designed entirely in tables, so I'm unsure how to actually go about working out what value I should give to the `.WebTables` property, there may be something like 50 `<table>` tags on the entire page, all nested into one huge mess so I'm not sure of the order and counting is a terrifying prospect.

What I do know is the `id` of the table. Is there any way to use the table's `id` instead of a number that refers to the table? Or at least a way to figure out what number the table is from it?

For now, I might just pull up the source code and go counting tables, but it would still be useful for future reference. Thanks.

Comment: "Data/Macro Recorder" is my best friend for WebQuery!

Answer (score -1):

You can use WebSelectionType with ID of table.
For example, this iqy file works with ID:

```
WEB
1
http://www.glav-dostavka.ru/prices/sbor/20120516175749-8424/?c=153396

Selection=price_table
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
```

since iqy describes pretty much the same as VBA can specify, i'm assuming you can use text

Comment: Doesn't answer the question as your solution is a different language.  How can we do this in vba?